# Why is it showing stackoverflowerror when i am trying to create an object in it's own class?

Tags: java, recursion, exception, stack-overflow

```
package inheritance;  

public class SingleInheritance {

//  SingleInheritance obj=new SingleInheritance();     Why does this line is not giving any error when I am creating a class's object in it's own class

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plumber rahul=new Plumber();   
        
        }

}
package inheritance;

class Plumber{
    
    Plumber ganesh=new Plumber();  
        // while  this one is giving the stackoverflowerror.
    }
```

It does not throws any error when I create the object of SingleInheritance class in it's own class but throws an error while I do the same thing in another class .[image: error]
I know It is silly to create object in it's own class but this happened when I was trying to do something else. I need an explanation to what is happening .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that there is recursively creation of your class `Plumber` objects and no condition that will terminate it.

Let us see the contents of your class `Plumber` and their instantiation.

```
class Plumber
{
   Plumber obj = new Plumber();
}
```

What do you think this does on creating a `new Plumber()` object.
It will instantiate a `new Plumber()` to `obj`, which will in return create another `new Plumber()` to `obj.obj`, and so on ..

You sure can keep an object a Plumber in same class, but you need to have a specific flow when you want to actually initialize it.

```
class Plumber
{
   Plumber obj;
   public Plumber()
   {
      if(/*condition*/)
      {
         obj = new Plumber();
      }
   }

   // You can also use some methods to do so
   public InstantiateObj()
   {
      obj = new Plumber();
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because you are not instantiating `SingleInheritance` class.
The code

```
public class SingleInheritance {

    SingleInheritance obj=new SingleInheritance(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Plumber rahul=new Plumber();   
    }
}
```

Is not creating a new instance of `SingleInheritance` because `main` is a static function.

If you change your code to:

```
public class SingleInheritance {

    SingleInheritance obj=new SingleInheritance(); 

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SingleInheritance rahul=new SingleInheritance();   
    }
}
```

You will get the same Stackoverflow exception because now `main` will instantiate `SingleInheritance`. The reason you get Stackoverflow is that `new Plumber()` calls its own constructor like other answers do explain.